# Upper case search is not working

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I've got a little problem with searching in my website.
I want to get some data from database and print it, but when i try to do data and searching key same - upper case it does not work anymore.?
https://pastebin.com/MuFkkVFS

```
$search[0] = strtoupper($search[0]);

$query = "
  SELECT * FROM data_magazine 
  WHERE UPPER(author_name) LIKE '%".$search[0]."%' 
  OR UPPER(author_surname) LIKE '%".$search[0]."%' 
  OR UPPER(rubric_title) LIKE '%".$search[0]."%' 
  OR UPPER(number_of_magazine) LIKE '%".$search[0]."%' 
  OR UPPER(year_of_magazine) LIKE '%".$search[0]."%' 

 ";
```

Comment: Is this straight ascii data? or is there a charset involved? what is the collation for the table columns?

Comment: If your collation on the table and columns end with *_ci, then you do not need to upper everything to do a search.

Comment: i'm using utf8_general_ci col. but it is not working

Comment: Please provide an example of text that is failing.  Also provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.